# 学校というのは、とにかく「みんな仲良く」で、「いつも心が触れ合って、みんなで一つだ」という、まさにここで私は「幻想」という言葉を使ってみたいのですが、「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような「友達幻想」というものが強調される場所のような気がします

Tags: translation

> 学校というのは、とにかく「みんな仲良く」で、「いつも心が触れ合って、みんなで一つだ」という、まさにここで私は「幻想」という言葉を使ってみたいのですが、「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような「友達幻想」というものが強調される場所のような気がします

Here is my try at it,

> 学校というのは、とにかく「みんな仲良く」で、「いつも心が触れ合って、みんなで一つだ」という、
> It is said that school is a place where  "everyone are getting along with each other, mutual touching and together as one". (Assumption: I've never heard this song)

> まさにここで私は「幻想」という言葉を使ってみたいのですが
> I want to try to use the word "idealised image" right here,

> 「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような「友達幻想」というものが強調される場所のような気がします
> I feel like it was emphasized by thing called "a fantasy friend" that was symbolized by a song, "become first grader"

---

I am not quite sure of the last part. Also from where should I start to translate? From the last word? And I'm confused about two ような and 受け身 here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic structure:

> 学校というのは、 (very long modifier here) 場所のような気がします。
>   I feel that school is (such-and-such) a place.

場所 is modified by a relative clause, 「友達幻想」というものが強調される:

> 学校というのは、**「友達幻想」というものが強調される場所**のような気がします。
>   I feel that school is **a place where something called "friend fantasy" is emphasized**.

友達幻想 is further modified by 「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような:

> 学校というのは、**「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような「友達幻想」**というものが強調される場所のような気がします。
>   I feel that school is a place where something called **"friend fantasy", as symbolized by a song named "When I Have Become a First Grader"**, is emphasized.

The song 「一年生になったら」 is further modified by とにかく「みんな仲良く」で「いつも心が触れ合って、みんなで一つだ」という:

> 学校というのは、**とにかく「みんな仲良く」で、「いつも心が触れ合って、みんなで一つだ」という、**「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような「友達幻想」というものが強調される場所のような気がします。
>   I feel that school is a place where something called "friend fantasy", as symbolized by a song named "When I Have Become a First Grader", **which says "Everyone should get along, touching one another's heart, together as one"**, is emphasized.

Finally, まさにここで私は「幻想」という言葉を使ってみたいのですが is a [parenthetical phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_(rhetoric)) that introduces an aside information (perhaps this could be the most tricky part in this sentence):

> 学校というのは、とにかく「みんな仲良く」で、「いつも心が触れ合って、みんなで一つだ」という、**まさにここで私は「幻想」という言葉を使ってみたいのですが**、「一年生になったら」という歌に象徴されるような「友達幻想」というものが強調される場所のような気がします。
>   I feel that school is a place where something called "friend fantasy" **(yes I want to use the word "fantasy" here)**, as symbolized by a song named "When I Have Become a First Grader", which says "Everyone should get along, touching one another's heart, together as one", is emphasized.

Comment: Ah thankyou so muchhh!! Thank you for trying your best to make me understood this sentence!! I think i will use your method every time i'm confuse too!!! And maybe i should link the first and last words to grasp the basic structure(?) ->学校というのは~~~~気がします and i think its better to translate from the last sentence(?)

Comment: Yes, a subject and a predicate can be insanely far away from each other in Japanese...

Comment: 細かいですが、「とにかく～という」が修飾してるのは「一年生になったら」ではなく「友達幻想」の方だと思います。事実その歌にはそういうくだりはないです。

Comment: @broccoliforest ですよねー…（「～という友達幻想」ってどう訳すんでしょう…）

Comment: @naruto 英語だと引用文のままだと置き所に困りますよね…^^; "or what they say --" みたいな感じでしょうか？