# Why is は used in phrases with はず, if they are formal nouns that take a subordinate clause?

Tags: grammar, particle-は, formal-nouns, subordinate-clauses

Based on what I understand, formal nouns like はず take up a subordinate clause, therefore taking が to mark the subject, but when I see examples such as

> あの人は若いはず

or

> あの本は高かったはずだ

It makes it look like my understanding is wrong.

When I tried to contemplate why, I just imagine that あの人 and あの本 aren't a part of the subordinate clause, but it is more of saying "that person/book is ～ はずだ".

If that may be the case can this also be applied to other formal nouns such as わけ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, 高い and 高かった are the short subordinate clauses that modify はず. Japanese relative clauses [can be very short](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/48859/5010). As you said, the word marked with は is working as a topic of the entire sentence.

あの人が若いはず lacks a topic, and this doesn't even look like a valid sentence to me. It's just a fragment roughly meaning "probable-ness of that person being young". Still, you can make the subordinate clause have a different subject using が:

> 彼はあの人が若いはずがないと思っている。
> He thinks that person should not be young.