# What does 人の手により in this sentence mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I have problems understanding following sentence, especially the meaning of 人の手により

> 新しいデザインを作るまで、多くの**人の手により**出尽くした感もあるけど、諦めません。

Does he speak here about other designers? Something like

> *Until a new design is finished, I sometimes feel like as if all design options are exhausted, but I don't give up.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, 多くの人の手 refers to (existing) efforts by many other people.

Grammatically speaking, there is a *[parenthetical](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/sentence/parenthetical-expression.htm) aside* in this sentence. That is, 多くの人の手により出尽くした感もあるけど has been inserted as an aside, as if it were in parentheses.

> 新しいデザインを作るまで、多くの人の手により出尽くした感もあるけど、諦めません。
>   Until a new design is finished — although I can't help feeling all design options have been already exhausted by other people's hands — I don't give up.

In general, Japanese けど/けれど/が/etc can sometimes work like this. You probably know they can [provide background/introductory information](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32826/5010) at the beginning of a sentence, but the same thing can happen in the middle of a sentence. Examples:

- 私の友人にドイツ人がいて、といってもここ数年は会っていないのです**が**、とてもビールについて詳しいですよ。
- 私は、ほかに誰も希望者がいなければです**けど**、佐藤さんを推薦したいと思います。
- 来週から1週間、本当はあまり行きたくないのだ**が**、アメリカへ出張することになっている。

Another example here: [Is my translation correct?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39604/5010)