# お正月には「初詣」といって…grammar

Tags: grammar, meaning, translation

In my text book I have a sentence I’m struggling with.
The paragraph reads
「日本人の生活を見ると、神棚と仏壇を祭る他にも、もっと色々な宗教的習慣や行事があることに気がつくだろう。まず、お正月には「初詣」といって、人々は神社やお寺にお参りに行き、お守りやお札をもらう。
The part that gets me is how after 初詣 there’s no というの or something I would have expected. Instead といって is written.
Can someone explain please!
Thanks

Comment: What would you have expected instead?

Comment: I tend to see って as an informal version of というのは. Therefore, to me といって just seems a middle point between both expressions, but the three of them (って, といって and というのは) would have thr same meaning. It may help you to review your textbook 上級へのとびら, pages 20 and 21 (in my edition), grammar points 13 and 15.

Answer (score 1):

"お正月には「初詣」という" doesn't make sense. On the other hand, the sentence in question would make perfect sense if it were not for `「初詣」といって`:

> お正月には、人々は神社やお寺にお参りに行き、お守りやお札をもらう。

So I think this `「初詣」といって` should be parsed like a [parenthetical aside](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/68193/5010). This type of ～といって is relatively common and it works like English "..., *known as ～*, ...".

> お正月には（「初詣」といって）人々は神社やお寺にお参りに行き…
> In *oshogatsu*, people visit shrines or temples... (we call this *hatsu-mode*)

Answer (score 0):

In this context, I would think of ...といって as expressing the idea "we could talk about New Years Day Observances"